# C# ActiveX exe?

Tags: c#, com, vb6, out-of-process

I need an out of process C# COM component to host a 32 bit VB6 COM object. I can't seem to figure out how to do this in C#. The closest analogue I can think of is an activex exe, but it doesn't appear that C# can do this. Due to client restrictions, I cannot use com+ or dllhost.exe. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on why it has to be out of process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question : [Is there an equivalent to out-of-process COM EXE in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/604776)